# Why Google BigQuery doesn't use partition date correctly when using views

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, data-partitioning

I have a date partitioned table (call it `sample_table`) with 2 columns, one to save dateTime in UTC and other to save timezone offset. I have a view on top of this table (call it `sample_view`). The view takes `_partitiontime` in from table and exposes that as `partitionDate` column and also there is another column `customerDateTime` which simply adds dateTime with timeZoneOffset.

When I query the `sample_table` directly using only `_partitiontime` bigquery scans far less data (131 MB).

```
select
  containerName,
  count(*)
from
  [sample_project.sample_table] 
where
  _partitiontime between timestamp('2016-12-12') and timestamp('2016-12-19')
  and customer = 'X'
  and containerName = 'XXX'
group by containerName
;
```

But when I run same query on the table with `dateTime` column to scan according to customer's local date time big query scans more (211MB). I expected less than 131MB or equal to 131MB.

```
select
  containerName,
  count(*)
from
  [sample_project.sample_table] 
where
  _partitiontime between timestamp('2016-12-12') and timestamp('2016-12-19')
  and DATE_ADD(dateTime, 3600, 'SECOND' ) between timestamp('2016-12-12 08:00:00') and timestamp('2016-12-19 15:00:00')
  and customer = 'X'
  and containerName = 'XXX'
group by containerName
;
```

When I run similar query against the `sample_view` with `partitionDate` bigquery scans more (399MB)

```
select
  containerName,
  count(*)
from
  [sample_project.sample_view] 
where
  partitionDate between timestamp('2016-12-12') and timestamp('2016-12-19')
  and customer = 'X'
  and containerName = 'XXX'
group by containerName
;
```

And when I run query against the view with `partitionDate` and use `customerDateTime` column as well bigquery scans even more (879MB)

```
select
  containerName,
  count(*)
from
  [sample_project.sample_view] 
where
  partitionDate between timestamp('2016-12-12') and timestamp('2016-12-19') and customerDateTime between timestamp('2016-12-12 08:00:00') and timestamp('2016-12-19 15:00:00')
  and customer = 'X'
  and containerName = 'XXX'
group by containerName
;
```

I'm not too sure whether I'm scanning right partitions from any of the queries above. Why do I see the differences between these queries? Is exposing _partitiontime as a new column  `partitionDate` a bad strategy? I'm not sure how else to use the partition date within Tableau without writing more queries. Please let me know if you require more details.

Comment: does your table have repeated fields?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) for the query instead, since legacy SQL has some limitations in terms of filter pushdown. I'm not very familiar with Tableau myself, but they have a [help page for BigQuery](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.html#examples_googlebigquery.html) that talks about switching between legacy and standard SQL.

Comment: This is interesting, after changing the view to support standard SQL the number of bytes scanned has gone down to 314MB, but it does take longer to run slightly (not sure why). Why does partitioning by date work differently in legacy SQL from standard SQL. I tried going through their docs but cannot get enough details.

Comment: Does this mean in order to use view with partition date, I'd have to use legacy SQL?

Comment: Standard SQL supports partitioned tables. Where did you see otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Just guess - the problem you see is because you have repeated fields. Legacy and Standard SQL deal differently with flattening result. Legacy SQL does flatten result thus you see not count of original records but rather number of repeated values in them. Whereas Standard SQL keep original structure. In Legacy SQL you need to take extra care of eliminating effect of Flattening, while in Standard SQL it is already taken care of

Comment: Thanks - do I have to use standard SQL to be able to use partition date effectively in my queries?

Comment: as I tried to make a point in my answer - the issue you see is most likely not really because of partitioned table! Both Legacy and Standard SQL support partitioned tables. Standard SQL will help you because it is more effectively deals with ARRAYS (repeated fields).

Comment: Ok - thanks, but I still can't get the queries against my queries to scan less data when I use legacy SQL against view. In fact it doesn't look like it's using partition date at all when using view.

Comment: agree. this part might be related to the partition used in view. the problem in answering your question is that it is too broad. I would suggest to separate different issues into different questions and post them separately. this way you have more/better chances to get them addressed. so far - for the current question - that's all I can help you with